# How to achieve generic interface and readable code?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following design problem in JAVA: I have the following Interface I1 that I want to use fr a number of classes A1, A2,... however the arguments in the getGain method 
should be specific to the implementation A1,A2....

```
public interface I1{  public Double getGain(I2 i2);}
```

I2 is itself an interface which has two implementations B1, B2.

Then I have two classes implementing this interface I1: A1, A2

```
 Class A1 implements I1{ 
       @Override  getGain(I2 i2){
       // here I expect the implementation B1 of class I2, 
       //as I may need to create new B1(...)
 }
```

and

```
 Class A2 implements I1{
    @Override
    getGain(I2 i2){
        //here I expect the implementation B2 of class I2, 
        //as I may need to create new B2(...)
    }
```

Solution 1:

```
public interface I1<K extends I2>{
    public Double getGain(K i2);
}
```

However I will to add this <> in any class using I1 which can be not readable at all.

Solution 2:
Lose the genericity in I1 and end up having

```
public interface I1{    
    public Double getGain(C1 i1);
}
public interface I2{    
    public Double getGain(C2 i2);
}
```

Is there a better solution?

What I meant is that now let's say I have some other generic class with for instance a method that should return I1 and that should be 
generic as well I have to carry the genericity of I1 inside the Calculator:

```
class P<K extends I2{
    I1<K> getI();
}
```

Moreover if now I have another 2 extra interfaces J2,K2.
And now if `I1<I extends I2, J extends J2, K extends K2>`

I have

```
class P<I extends I2, J extends J2, K extends K2>{
    I1<I> get1();
    J1<J> get2();
    K1<K> get3();
}
```

Maybe that's normal but I'm more of a newbie in generics :)

Comment: What is `getCol`?  Is that a typo?

Comment: I disagree that Solution 1 will cause bad readability.

Comment: Agree with @kocko--I think this is the best.  The only other thing I can think of is to have `A1` and `A2` check at run-time that their parameter has the expected type, using `instanceof`, and throw an exception otherwise.  But you lose the ability to check at compile time.

Comment: @ajb yes it is a typo

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer. I have edited my questions above

Comment: Are you implementing the adapter pattern? Then don't pass a C1 or C2 to each method. Just pass it to the constructor and specify the actual type that this adapter implementation expects.

Comment: The code examples presented are a little too abstract for me to understand. Often if you end up with long generic argument lists, that's a code smell: you may be violating the single-responsibility principle, for example. But it's hard to give any advice without understanding the reason why all of these generics are occurring.

Answer (score 0):

> However I will to add this `<>` in any class using I1 which can be not readable at all.

This is perfectly reasonable. Most Java developers are fully prepared to type two more characters when implementing a generic class.

Your Solution 1 is the generally accepted way, and the one that will give you the best readability and code reuse in this case.

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer. I have edited my questions above

Comment: Are you copying and pasting the same comment to all answers?

Comment: I am new here, I don't know if everyone get update if I only comment one answer...

Answer (score 0):

Even if we accept your premise that generic class names (names with `<>` in them) are "unreadable", given that you expect only two classes to implement I1, most of your code will probably refer to the classes A1 and A2 directly.  These class names won't have any generic parameters.

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer. I have edited my questions above